# Deploying a Web Application on IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis, windows-server-2008

I am having a problem deploying my asp.NET 4.0 web application on the web server. One of the problems is that when deploying, by going to Publish...Select FileSystem...Set the Target Location of the Server , this does not copy all the references (the only dll's which are there are the class libraries which I created), for example OracleDataReader dll.

Any ideas why this is happening? should I be doing something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on `OracleDataReader.dll` assembly in "Solution Explorer", select "Properties" and set "Copy Local" to "true". This will copy the assembly to `bin`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it - However some dll's do not have that option (Crystal Reports DLLs). These allow me to Embed Interop Types, what is that?

Comment: @Ryan, Crystal Reports is just plain evil in my not so humble opinion because it does a lot of COM registration which requires the runtime to be installed on the target server. :( We're going through that right now trying to determine the magical mixture of .NET versions and SP releases to support our developers. If anyone has any clues I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @Greg Wojan - I am in the same position as you are. When publishing our asp.NET application on the server, it is always missing the assembly files. Not to mention we have other problems with using odp.NET with our database.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set `Copy Local` to `true` for these DLLs that you require.